# Animating TextArea height causes Text to jump

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to animate the height of TextArea when the user changes the content.

**When adding content, the height increases and causes text jumps**.
When deleting content, the height animates as expected and text doesn't jump

Could someone please explain why it's happening and how to prevent it?

Here's the relevant code

```js
import React from "react";
import TextAreaAutoSize from "react-textarea-autosize";


export default function App() {
  return (
    <TextAreaAutoSize
      style={{
        overflow: "hidden",
        padding: 0,
        transition: "all .3s"
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Here's the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-glade-j5311?file=/src/App.js

Video of bug https://streamable.com/puwply

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with react, but seems like height is being reset? Another clue: when I click onto the folders on the left and then back onto the browser, the jumping no longer occurs

Comment: I checked but the text still jumps around when content is added even after clicking the folders. @Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the text gets the new height immediately while you give the container a transition time of 0.3s. So for 0.3 sec the text is higher than the box. I do not have an easy solution, however I prefer the looks without animation.